# pgfplots generates extra x steps from csv

Tags: csv, pgfplots

I try to load data from a csv and set the x ticks to years but for some reason, pfgplots creates intermediate 0.5 years with no corresponding y data points.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)


\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=0.9\textwidth,
        title={Niederschlag in den letzten 60 Jahren},
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
]   

        \addplot[   ] table[x=year, y=bla, col sep=semicolon] {test.csv};
        
    \end{axis}
    %\begin{axis}[width=0.9\textwidth,
    %   title={Niederschlag in den letzten 60 Jahren},
    %   x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    %   axis y line*=right,
    %   axis x line=none,]
    %   \addplot[draw=red,ultra thick] table[x=year, y=nr, col sep=semicolon] {fire_data.csv};
    %\end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following graph:
[image]

from where does it get the .5 years?

This is the test.csv:

```
year;bla
2016;2
2017;1
2018;4
2019;4
```

Comment: Unless you specify the tick marks, you have no control over their values.  There are a number of ways to do that.  See section 4.15 (page 336) of the pgfplots manual.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is provided by adding `xtick = data` as part of the `axis` environment parameters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).